# Creating HTML5-based apps for the Mac App Store

Tags: html, mac-app-store

The new Tweetdeck for the Mac is supposedly HTML5-based:

http://www.cultofmac.com/134237/tweetdeck-releases-html5-based-app-in-the-mac-app-store/

Anyone know how to build a HTML5 app for the Mac App Store like this? I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 6):

My guess is they do something similar to what [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) does - add a webview in an XCode project. Webviews are basically embedded browsers that can run html5 and javascript. Then, they code their pages in html5 and can call their dataservices via ajax.

Here is actually a tutorial on how to add your html5 code to a webview in xcode: http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-embed-html5-into-a-native-mac-osx-app/

Comment: @user564320 - I've updated my answer with a tutorial on how Lost Decade Games converted their Chrome App to a Native Mac App using just this technique.

Answer (score 5):

Check out this http://www.tidesdk.org/ build apps with html5

Answer (score 1):

Today you have some great tools made to build Mac OS X applications with HTML5/CSS3 and JavaScript. Like Sentenza Desktop : http://codecanyon.net/item/sentenza-desktop-for-mac/4070984

Answer (score 0):

http://nwjs.io/

NW.js lets you call all Node.js modules directly from DOM and enables a new way of writing applications with all Web technologies. It was previously known as "node-webkit" project.