# Can a tutorial for Xcode 4 be used with Xcode 6?

Tags: html, macos, xcode4, xcode6

I've never used Objective X, or Xcode, or developed any software for OS X, but I'm trying to convert an HTML5 website into a standalone app to run on OS X, so I can get it running full-screen, i.e. without the browser location bars and other chrome that I don't seem to be able to remove from Safari or Google Chrome.

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491261/981959) about creating a native HTML5 app for OS X I tried following the steps in the [linked tutorial](http://www.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-embed-html5-into-a-native-mac-osx-app/) on a machine running Mavericks (10.9.5) and Xcode 6.1.1, but none of the steps seem to make sense for Xcode 6.

For example, step 4:

> In your Xcode window, under Overview / Groups & Files, expand WebViewExample / Frameworks by clicking the arrow icon.

I don't see an "Overview", but in the project navigator I added the WebKit.framework as a linked framework.

I don't see "Resources" either, which step 6 talks about:

> On the same level as Frameworks, expand Resources by clicking the arrow icon.

Where do I put the resources (i.e. the html files and images to open in the webview)?

I tried copying the code from steps 10 and 11 into the relevant `.h` and `.m` files, but then for step 12 I don't know how to find an Interface Builder.

Is it even possible to follow these steps on Xcode 6?

I tried building the project with what I'd managed so far, and get the error described at [Existing ivar 'title' for unsafe_unretained property 'title' must be __unsafe_unretained](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8368157/981959) for the `window` variable.

I "fixed" the error by just letting the compiler generate the ivar (or I think that's what I did! I have never used ObjC, but I removed the body of the interface in the `.h` header).

That ran, but opened a blank window, presumably because I hadn't created any resources folder so there was no HTML file at this location:

```
NSString *htmlPath = [resourcesPath stringByAppendingString:@"/htdocs/index.html"];
```

I'd love to put the files there, but I don't know where the `resourcesPath` is meant to be for this project!

(I tried adding my HTML files to the project, at the top level since I don't have a Resources folder, but that didn't change anything.)

After giving up trying to create the app from scratch I downloaded the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/lostdecade/web_view_example) and tried to open the .xcodeproj file, but in the project navigator the project says "1 target, missing base SDK". I set the base SDK, and it works ... but I can't copy pieces from that project into my own because the project structure is completely different.

So mostly I'd like to know if trying to use that tutorial is hopeless on Xcode 6, but if not where do I put my "Resources" files?

Should I just give up and use [TideSDK](http://www.tidesdk.org/), which looks quite promising?

Answer (score 1):

A lot has changed from 4-6, I myself tried to follow some tutorials which got me so lost I dropped the project. I know this might not be of help but from my little experience look for something written tutorial to help if there is no videos out for 6